# How to add an event listener when an element is transformed?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing a responsive website by using Bootstrap 3 with many features, one of them is when the website is displayed on a mobile a drop down menu is displayed ( on desktop I have a normal menu and on the mobile version it transform into a collapsing drop down menu) now my problem is that I need an event listener that is able to listen when this normal menu is transformed into this collapsing drop down menu, Is there any way to do that? Many thanks.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="container-sm visible-sm visible-xs container visible-md visible-lg">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Left Menu</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div id="sideNavBox" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">
            <!-- A lot of code that I included in the dropdown menu -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid rgb(241, 241, 241);
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 695px;
}
```

So basically how can I add an event listener that detect when my menu is transformed into a collapsing drop down menu?

Comment: Can't you use a window.matchMedia? something like: 'if (window.matchMedia("YourMediaRule").matches)...'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.matchMedia` to create such an event, see [minimal code example here](http://jsfiddle.net/3nrfp0xz/):

```
var mql = window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 768px)'),
    handleMQL = function(mql) {
        if (mql.matches) {
            console.log('MATCH');
            // Media query does match
            // fire your on event here 

        } else {
            console.log('UNMATCH');
            // Media query does not match anymore
            // fire your off event here 
        }
    };


mql.addListener(handleMQL);
// this is optional (in case you need the state on page load)
// see info below.
handleMQL(mql);
```

The listener fires when there is a change in the target media query's state. If you need the media query's state on page load, create a function to handle state change and you can also call the function on its own, like the example above.

In case you'll need older browser support, you could use a polyfill like [matchMedia.js](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js)